# iOS UITextField not clearing when editing

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextfield, textfield, placeholder

I have a standard UITextField that I have added to a UITableViewCell and whenever I go to edit it, the text that is in it will not clear out. I have tried placing a placeholder and that too will not clear when editing. What's going on?

```
if (indexPath.row == 1) {
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Device ID";
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        deviceID = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(115, 11, 388, 22)];
        deviceID.delegate = self;
        deviceID.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
        deviceID.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15];
        deviceID.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        deviceID.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
        deviceID.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
        deviceID.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
        deviceID.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
        deviceID.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
        deviceID.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        deviceID.delegate = self;
        deviceID.clearsOnBeginEditing = YES;
        deviceID.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:DEVICE_ID];
        [deviceID setEnabled:YES];
        [cell addSubview:deviceID];
    }

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldClear:(UITextField *)textField {

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Have you included the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol in your interface?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are adding multiple instances of same textfield on to the cell whenever `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called. Create textfield in `viewDidLoad` and add on to this cell. It should work.

An alternate way is to subclass your `UITableViewCell` and add this textFiled as a property of that in its `init` method. Then you can set value as `cell.textField.text = @"some value";`

If you add this line in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`,

```
deviceID = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(115, 11, 388, 22)];
```

It will get called whenever the table view is reloading and you will lose the references of previous textfields. So you need to make sure that you are creating only one textfield and adding it to tableview cell. This will also make sure that you have only a single textfield created in the cell.

Comment: Ahhhh that's why. Thanks I didn't think about that. Thank you.

Comment: So I probably should just subclass a UITableViewCell?

Comment: @JonErickson, Yes, that is better in this case. check my answer now. I had edited with that suggestion. If you create this textfield in subclass of tableview cell's init method, you can use `cell.textField.text = @"some value";` to set value and `cell.textField.hidden = YES;` to hide it in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

Comment: Sorry about the downvote :( but why wouldn't the Delegate method not work (I am new iOS developer and want to Learn more about iOS) :)

Comment: The problem isn't that the delegate method isn't working, it is working, but it is the fact that there a several UITextFields stacked on one another every time the UITableView is refreshed and every time the tableview is reloaded, the pointer to the UITextField is lost, that is why I have to subclass a UITableViewCell.

Comment: @iProgrammed, So did you downvote? The problem wasnt with the delegate method not working. It is just that multiple textfields were getting added on top of other which gives the feeling that previous text is not editable. It has nothing to do with a delegate method.

Comment: I have added he UITableViewCell subclass and it works fine, but how would I create a pointer to the textfield text, outside of the cellForForAtIndexPath delegate method?

Comment: @JonErickson, So is this a static table cell? If it is static, you can go for the first approach of creating in `viewDidLoad` and then accessing that textfield as `self.textfield.text` anywhere in your code. There are other ways to get it using your current approach.

Comment: Yeah it is static. But then how would I add the UITextField subview to the cell? I thought that the actual piece of code, [cell.contentView addSubview:textfield] is what creates the stacks of textfields in the cell every time the table is reloaded.

Comment: @JonErickson, In that case, you just have to move `deviceID = [[UITextField alloc] ..` to viewDidLoad and declare `deviceID` as an `@property` in your .h file. `addSubview:textfield` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` wont cause any issue here. It will add only one instance which was created in `viewDidLoad`. Calling addSubview multiple times on same instance wont do any harm.

Answer (score 1):

What if you try this delegate method:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
   [textField setText:@""];
}
```

Comment: Look at the answer above, it's because every time the table is reloaded, it re-adds the subview, creating stacks of UITextFields on top of each other. I need to subclass a UITableViewCell in order to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following in another post (pertaining to views, generally):

```
[self.view.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector: @selector(removeFromSuperview)];
```

and converted to this:

```
[cell.contentView.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector: @selector(removeFromSuperview)];
```

Works perfectly to resolve problem in this thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
[deviceID removeFromSuperview];
devideID = nil;
deviceID = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(115, 11, 388, 22)];
...
```

While the accepted answer works, if you don't want to delegate the responsibility to the ViewController of having to create the UITextField then use this